# Is there an opposite of an exclusion for Windows Defender?

Tags: windows-10, security, windows-defender

If I had a file that I know is safe, but Windows Defender thinks it's unsafe, I could [add an exclusion](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/add-an-exclusion-to-windows-security-811816c0-4dfd-af4a-47e4-c301afe13b26#:%7E:text=Go%20to%20Start%20%3E%20Settings%20%3E%20Update,%2C%20file%20types%2C%20or%20process.). My question is, can I do the opposite?

I have a file that Defender thinks is safe, but I want it to consider it a threat instead. If a user on my machine decides to install `TheAppIDontLike.exe` or download `ThePictureIDontLike.jpg` then I want Defender to block it, even though it's not a known security risk.

Comment: No, but if the computer is domain joined, you can use group policy to block apps with a certain name.

Comment: Windows Defender rules are not user-modifiable. Windows has the ability to [Prevent Users From Running Certain Programs](https://www.technipages.com/prevent-users-from-running-certain-programs/) through Group Policy or the matching registry entries, but this only works for Explorer ([link](https://admx.help/?Category=Windows_10_2016&Policy=Microsoft.Policies.WindowsTools::DisallowApps)). If this helps with the problem, I could put up an answer.

Comment: @harrymc I think that would be helpful, thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Windows Defender rules are not user-modifiable, but Windows has
the ability to
[Prevent Users From Running Certain Programs](https://www.technipages.com/prevent-users-from-running-certain-programs/)
through Group Policy or the matching registry entries, although
this is limited for programs started via Explorer
([link](https://admx.help/?Category=Windows_10_2016&Policy=Microsoft.Policies.WindowsTools::DisallowApps)).

**Option 1 – Group Policy**

- Run `gpedit.msc`
- Navigate to
  *User Configuration > Administrative Templates > System*.
- Double-click the policy
  "Don’t run specified Windows applications"
- Set the policy to Enabled and click Show
- Add the programs to the "List of disallowed applications",
  such as `itunes.exe`, `bittorent.exe`
- Click OK.

**Option 2 – Registry Editor**

- Run `regedit`
- Position to
  `HKEY_CURRENT_USER\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Policies\Explorer`
- Right-click a blank area on the right side and select
  *New > DWORD (32-bit) Value* and name it `DisallowRun`
- Right-click a blank area on the right side and select
  *New > String Value* and name it `1`
- Double click the value and set it to the name of the executable
  to block
- Continue with items named `2` and `3` etc.

Comment: That GPO is no real protection since it only checks the names. Windows already has software restriction policies ("SRP") and Applocker ("SRPv2") included which should be preferred since they allow to blacklist hashes of executables/scripts and thus offer real protection.